# Focus on Excel VSTO WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, excel, vsto

I'm hosting WPF application within an Excel VSTO Add-in and it works fine onload, however after minimizing the WPF dialog, can't seem to get it to activate (focus) again using code.
Have tried:

```
    this.Show();
    this.Activate();
    this.BringIntoView();
    this.Focus();
```

But none of them work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution of somesort:
On Close, I used an event handler to set it the visiblity to Hidden:

```
private void ClientOnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs cancelEventArgs)
        {
            cancelEventArgs.Cancel = true;
            _client.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
```

To handle focus a minimized WPF application, I set the windowstate to Normal:

```
public void ShowDialog()
        {
            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            this.Show();
        }
```

This seems to work ok.