# Word loses focus (minimized) after closing non-modal form

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, vsto

I have a problem with the Word Add-in I'm developing.

**The problem:**
If I open non-modal form called Form1, and inside this form I press a button that opens another modal form called Form2. Now I close both forms, but Word windows is losing focus and minimized.

Note that this is *not happening* when I just open Form1 and close it.

When I open a non-modal form (let's call it Form1) by using `Form1.Show(IWin32Window);`

where the IWin32Window object is created by this method:

```
public static MyWin32Window getWordWindow()   
{            
    IntPtr wordWindow = NativeMethods.FindWindowW("OpusApp", Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Caption + " - Microsoft Word");
    MyWin32Window myWin = new MyWin32Window(wordWindow);            
    return myWin;        
}
```

The problem occurs **only** when I open another form from Form1, let's say Form2 is opened, but Form2 is modal form and opened with:

```
Form2.ShowDialog();
```

It works fine, but when I close Form2 and then Form1, the Word window is minimized. How can I prevent this behavior?

I also tried setting Form1 as the owner of Form2, like this:

```
Form2.ShowDialog(this);
```

but same result.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003559/focus-on-excel-vsto-wpf-application

Comment: @Kiru thanks but this is winforms and not WPF

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was able to resolve this problem by using

```
Form.Show();
```

instead of `ShowDialog()`.